# Im trying to combine two data frames with same request Id using pandas but unable to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the excel data as follows :

```
 Df1                Df2              
                               
Id Text           Id Text           
12 abc            12 rtx
13 xyz            12 jkl
14 wxy            13 nmo
```

`I want the data as follows:`

```
Df3  
ID   Text
12   abc,rtx,jkl
13   xyz,nmo
14   wxy
```

Can someone please help me to get the output.

Comment: please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenate the dataframes, then groupby `ID`:

```
(pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False)
   .groupby('Id', as_index=False)
   ['Text'].apply(','.join)
)
```

Output:

```
   Id         Text
0  12  abc,rtx,jkl
1  13      xyz,nmo
2  14          wxy
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I get the error opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Comment: This gave me a comma separated values of column names but not the row values . The output looks something like this    ID     Text
                                                      12     ID, Text, Textname

Comment: @Sanjana replace `agg` with `apply`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quang Hoang and DavidErickson. I could get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can append `df2` to `df1` and then group, using `reset_index()` at the end:

```
df1['Text'] = df1['Text'].astype(str)
df2['Text'] = df2['Text'].astype(str)
df1.append(df2).groupby('Id')['Text'].agg(','.join).reset_index()

    Id         Text
0   12  abc,rtx,jkl
1   13      xyz,nmo
2   14          wxy
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I get an error saying :
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @Sanjana you might have missing data which represented by `NaN` values in your data.

Comment: You can set the data type to a string. See answer.